# Integrating PayPal library into swift project using Cocoapods, not finding Library

Tags: c++, ios, swift, paypal, cocoapods

So I have used CocoaPods to attain the PayPal library within my application which is a Swift iOS file, but I am receiving this error.

ld: library not found for -lPayPalMobile
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have played around with the build settings and paths that have seemed to be problematic for other people having similar issued with the same error for different libraries. I have also used another Obj-C library with Cocoapod with Swift with no issues.

Does anyone know how I could remedy this issue or any other things I should try?

Comment: are you opening the xworkspace instead of the xproject

Comment: Yeah, I open the xworkspace

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866314/paypal-ios-sdk-using-cocoapods-throws-error-in-bridging-header