# PayPal-iOS-SDK using cocoapods throws error in bridging header

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, sdk, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate **Paypal** sdk in a **swift** project using **cocoapods**. I tried to `import PayPal_iOS_SDK` module but it throws the following error

> No such module 'PayPal_iOS_SDK'

With `#import <PayPal-iOS-SDK/PayPalMobile.h>` in bridging header compiler is unable to find headers.

Is there anything wrong I am doing in bridging header?

Comment: try importing `#import "PayPalMobile.h"`

Comment: I already tried with no luck.!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by setting `Pods/PayPal-iOS-SDK/**` in **User Header Search Paths**. Later I was able to `#import "PayPalMobile.h"` in the bridging headers.

Comment: @Divyesh Makwana can you give more details on the solution? Where exactly can user header search paths be set?

Comment: @user2363025 just for reference you can get the option "User Header Search Path" on Build Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed adding the header file path in "project"-"build setting"-"swift_objc_bridging_header" .
[image]